# Wicket: Paginate a huge result query

Tags: wicket

I'm getting over 100 MB of results from an API which I need to paginate because it takes over 10 minutes to sort. All of the results are reglar JSON Objects

How could I paginate this amount of data using wicket?

Answer (score 2):

100MB is a an amount that you better do not keep in memory! Better store it (temporarily) into some Document NoSQL database (like Couchbase, MongoDB, or similar). Then use the database query language to read one page at a time.

Answer (score 2):

Wicket offers components working with an IDataProvider, an interface that support data paging.

- https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/guide/8.x/single.html#_pageable_repeaters

You'll probably have to cache your 100 MB result somewhere, since you don't want to reload the data on each paging. You should not store it inside a component though, or it will be serialized along with the containing page.